# Whether using of neural network for optimization is correct?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am doing a project on dynamic price optimization which uses neural Network. As per my knowledge neural network classically used for classification. In our context we are using for predicting optimal price of a product. By training the model with already existing information on a product. It predicts optimal selling price for a product by using the input like cost of production, delivery time, after sales service etc.For a test set we are getting following result after training.

```
Actual price (Of benchmark or dataset)     Predicted by neural net   
 375                                        394.23
 146                                        171.98
1211                                       1210.70
```

Here my question which is burning me is as it is continuous data.Here my question which is burning me is as it is continuous data. Can we apply neural network and predict in the manner we have done.

Below is train data set. We need to train or predict the last column (selling price) based on the other inputs.

> `Cost of`  `Product`  `Delivery`  `After`
>   `Productn` `Quality`   `Time`   `Sales.Service`
>   `871.1901`    `1139.99`    `895.13`   `1029.98`
>   `296.9901`     `329.95`    `329.73`   `334.99`
>   `118.7901`     `159.99`    `129.26`   `149.98`
>   `791.9901`     `949.99`    `810.68`  `979.98`
>   `989.9901`     `1099.99`  `1054.99`   `1169.98`

We are using neural net of r library, **Learning rate was 0.05 and iteration is 20, back prop algorithm .**
I am in dilemma whether to use neural network for price optimization or not.
Please do suggest me whether to go along with neural network and take me to right direction.I am in dilemma whether to use neural network for price optimization or not. Please do suggest me whether to go along with neural network and take me to right direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the [*Hopfield model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network); it was used as one of the early ideas of optimization. But neural networks will in general easily get stuck in a local optimum.

Comment: This being said, neural networks are in general not the "right tool" for optimization. You don't really specify the problem you're facing so it is hard to give a good optimization technique. Perhaps *linear programming* will be sufficient.

Comment: I would not be concerned about the data being continuous. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559843/what-are-good-examples-of-solutions-to-neural-network-problems?rq=1 -- there are a few non-discrete-output problems there aside from the usual pattern-recognition applications. Also see "Control Systems" in http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/features.html#simulink-blocks-and-control-systems-applications. The bigger concern is whether you can train the network adequately.

Comment: This really doesn't seem like an optimization problem in the mathematical sense. It seems you have one value per item which you want to predict; that's just regression. And NNs are perfectly suited to that since that's what they naturally do, and they also naturally work with continuous variables.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're doing is called *regression*, not *optimization*: You're (more or less) assuming that the relation between your input variables (cost of production, delivery time...) and price is a (more or less) smooth function, and you want to approximate that function using a few known values. That's regression. And, yes, neural networks can be used for that. (Whether or not it's a good solution to your problem, I do not know. But the fact that the output is continuous is per se *not* a problem for a neural network.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that NNs are perfectly suited to this application, but it will all be in the way that you go about building it. Although I gave an answer a couple of days ago about how one might use a multi-layer perceptron for classification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361682/neural-network-error-oscillating-with-each-training-example/30378425#30378425), I did it using a continuous output.

An example where I did something similar is looking at how different industrial process parameters might impact on the efficiency of a process. I did this with 18 process inputs and got great results when following it up experimentally. In terms of visualisation, I can only show how two independent variables impact on efficiency whilst everything else is constant, but you’re obviously not bound to that restriction when you actually use the NN.

[image: graph]

The potential difficulty you will have is in the distinction between interpolation and extrapolation when you produce your “response surface”. Interpolation should always be sought – that is, you try and teach the model with all the extreme conditions that you think you will encounter. For example, if you train the NN for a range of examples that has a production cost ranging from £0.10/kg product and £50/kg product, you’re reasonably safe asking for predictions in that range. If you ask for a prediction for something costing £100/kg, you’re now extrapolating in that parameter and your results might not make sense e.g. in the past I have had predictions of 120% efficiency (impossible).

Of course, the above is far easier said than done. For me it was easy because I could test every combination I wanted to in order to confine the problem. It could be that your lowest production cost item (i.e. the one that defines the extreme in that parameter) could have middle-of-the-road quantities for the other input variables. Really it’s a case of gathering as much data as possible and seeing if the model makes sense.

Obviously you can never be certain of success, but if you’ve already got an NN structure in place then I would certainly recommend at least the following modifications before abandoning an NN approach:
-   Change the learning rule. Bayesian regularization has always been vastly superior to levenberg-marquardt in my applications. 
-   Change the number of neurons in the hidden layer

If you’re using something like Matlab for your NN then you can blast through so many models in such a short space of time, you will rapidly and (basically) effortlessly be able to determine if this methodology is suitable.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.. It was  very helpful!!....I had sent the test set sample. I would like to send the training set sample, to get more clarity on it..The training set used are:
Production Cost  ,  Product Quality Delivery Time After  Sales Service
871.1901 1139.99 895.13 1029.98
296.9901 329.95 329.73 334.99
118.7901 159.99 129.26 149.98
791.9901 949.99 810.68 979.98
989.9901 1099.99 1054.99 1169.98

              And I would be helpful if you can suggest me the other approach that can be used for price optimization instead of neural network??

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot make sense of the data you have listed, and I'm also not sure that anyone else but me can see that you have posted here, as you responded to me. However, I think your training set consists of 5 different examples? Of all the models and approaches I am familiar with, I wouldn't trust any of them based on such a small training set; a NN has way too much flexibility to misinterpret the relationship between your inputs. I personally would default back to something much more fundamental using Excel, perhaps with simple regression. I'm not sure.