# Non-converging Neural Network in C

Tags: c, neural-network

I wrote my first feed-forward neural network in C, using the sigmoid `1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x))` as activation function and gradient descent to adjust the weights. I tried to approximate `sin(x)` to make sure my network works. However, the output of the neuron on the output layer seems to always oscillate between the extreme values 0 and 1 and the weights of the neurons grow to absurd sizes, no matter how many hidden layers there are, how many neurons are in the hidden layer(s), how many training samples I provide, or even what the target outputs are.

1) Are there any standard 'tried and tested' data sets used to proof-test neural networks for errors? If yes, what structures work best (e.g. numbers of neuron(s) in the hidden layer) to converge to the desired output?

2) Are there any common errors that generate the same symptoms? I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361682/neural-network-error-oscillating-with-each-training-example), but the issue was because of faulty data, which I believe is not my case.

3) Is there any preferred way of training the network? In my implementation I cycle through the training sets and adjust the weights *each time*, then rinse and repeat ~1000 times. Is there any other order that works better?

Comment: What is your final activation function? Is it also sigmoid? Then you might have problems with the fact that sin might be negative.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko To be clear, I just took 50 random real numbers between 0 and 1, and used the sin(x) of each one as the output target. So the numbers are all positive and between 0 and 1. I'm also not sure what you mean with final activation function?

Comment: Final activation is an activation function in last layer. Ok - So what were your learning rates and lost function for this task? Have you used MSE?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I also used a sigmoid as activation function on the output layer, and no supplementary function on top of that - I directly compare the output of the last layer with the targets. I tried different learning rates, from 0.7 to as low as 0.01, but the oscillating phenomenon is still present, just a bit slower. As for the cost function, I indeed used the squared difference between the output and the desired target. But now that I think of it, would it make more sense to calculate the mean squared difference for the whole traning set before adjusting the weights?

Comment: So - before you updated it after every example? It's called SGD and might cause some problems. You could compute the error on a whole set or use batch learning instead (when you are updating your weights after computing errors for e.g. 20 examples). Also learning rate 0.7 might be to big.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Yes, that was what I was using, without knowing the name of it. I tried it now with only updating after testing 20 training entries, however, my network converges to '1' as output regardless of the target output, so I guess I made a mistake in calculating the gradient somewhere. On a related topic, are there usually any limitations on the values of the weights, i.e. are they kept bounded within a certain interval, or always positive?

Comment: Usually divergence of weights are considered as bad sign. That's why usually additional term in cost function is add to keep weights within reasonable range. Please read about L1 and L2 weight penalty. It might be useful. And why are you implementing this network from scratch in C? Is there any particular reason or you simply choose to start with C?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko This is for an undergrad project, and the platform imposed is C. Which makes finding code examples online a bit harder, since Python seems to be much more popular for NNs :(. Thank you for the L1 and L2 weight penalty ideas, I'll have a look. I also found a method for [gradient checking](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Gradient_checking_and_advanced_optimization), which could be useful for verifying that the programming part of the code is correct

Comment: I wrote an answer to sum up our discussion. I also wrote an additional comment about sigmoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to sum up:

1. Assuming that your gradient propagation works properly usually the values of parameters like topology, learning rate, batch size or value of a constant connected with weight penalty (L1 and L2 decay) are computed using a techniques called grid search or random search. It was empirically proved that random search performs better in this [task](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/practical-hyperparameter-optimization-random-vs-grid-search).
2. The most common reason of weight divergence is wrong learning rate. Big value of it might make learning really hard. But on the other hand - when learning rate is too small - learning process might take a really long time. Usually - you should *babysit* the learning phase. The specified instruction might be found e.g. [here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#baby).
3. In your learning phase you used a technique called SGD. Usually - it may achieve good results but it's vulnerable to variance of data sets and big values of learning rates. What I advice you is to use batch learning and set a batch size as additional learning parameter learnt during grid or random search. You can read about here e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70761/what-is-the-difference-between-online-and-batch-learning).
4. Another thing which you might consider is to change your activation function to `tanh` or `relu`. There are a lot of problems with saturation regions of `sigmoid` and it usually needs a proper initialization. You can read about it [here](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf).

Comment: This is more information than I could hope for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh I already tried to before, but it says I first need 15 'reputation', so you'll have to make due with my gratitude ;-)